# How can update project from Git in my Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse, git, macos

I have config my Git repository on my Windows pc and my Mac Osx.
In this git repository, I have my Java project and I used Eclipse with IDE.

Now to commit change from eclipse, I can do, right click on project, team, commit. After that, I open Git view, then I do, right click on Git, then select PUSH. This works.

Now the problem is to update the other Eclipse on Mac for example. So this is what I can see from eclipse:

[image]

Now, to view the update I do right click on origin/EasyAssistenza under "Remote Tracking" then I click Synchronize with workspace. Nut this operation sometimes works and sometimes not works.

What is the correct operation to do update my repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GO to the MAin Git project origin/EasyAssistenza and do a Pull... which will pull in all the changes you have committed and then you can do rebase on branches...